# VIM Executing a key command in a function

Tags: vim

I have a function, and I want to execute a key command, but I get the error Trailing characters:

```
function! MyFunction()
  if condition
    <C-W><C-W>
  else
    :some_other_command
  endif
endfunction
```

It doesn't like the <C-W><C-W>

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The general answer is to use the `:normal` command, like

```
:exe "normal \<C-W>\<C-w>"
```

The `:execute` approach is the readable way to get `:normal` to recognize special characters like control-key combinations.  The other approach is

```
:normal ^W^W
```

where each`^W` is one character inserted by typing <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>.

Comment: If I use `^W` in a script than it opens in binary mode. How to avoid that or should I prefer to use `:exe`?

Answer (score 3):

Use **feedkeys** function. NOTE that ^W is NOT "^" + "W" but actually type "Ctrl-V Ctrl-W". It's a special character.

```
function! MyFunction()
  if condition
    call feedkeys("^W^W")  
  else
    :some_other_command
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: This answer worked best for me. For some reason: `execute "normal c5l`" doesn't end up in insert mode. `call feedkeys("c5l")` does. Thanks man!