# Running a vim key combination on startup

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc`, I've got the lines

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * TagbarOpen
```

This results in a layout with two sidebars and a centre column containing the main editing buffer (i.e. the file I'm editing), but with the cursor in the NERDTree sidebar - resulting in the Tagbar being collapsed by default. What I want to do is execute the keystroke combination `<C>l` (which I've mapped to the command to move the cursor one buffer to the right) between the NERDTree opening and the Tagbar being toggled - but so far, I haven't managed to get the cursor to move. So far, i've tried using both

```
autocmd VimEnter * <C>l
autocmd VimEnter * normal <Ctrl+l>
```

... between the two above first lines, but neither of these work.

How do I go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM Executing a key command in a function](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46827/vim-executing-a-key-command-in-a-function)

Comment: See the link above. You can put `execute "normal \<C-L>"` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: That solution and the answers in the linked-to question don't work.

Comment: You're right, the questions are not really duplicates. I've combined the information from that link with what you had so far. Please take a look below and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command to go to the window to the right is `<C-w>l`. You can execute that with

```
:execute "normal! \<C-w>l"
```

But for the `<C-w>` commands, there's a special `:wincmd` that makes this easier. So just skip your custom mapping, and do:

```
autocmd VimEnter ...
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd l
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further consideration, I admit that the question is not really a duplicate of [VIM Executing a key command in a function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46827/vim-executing-a-key-command-in-a-function).

You were on the right track with `autocmd VimEnter`, you were missing the `execute` command:

```
:help execute
:exe[cute] {expr1} ..   Executes the string that results from the evaluation    
                        of {expr1} as an Ex command.
```

Taking the syntax for executing a key combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> from the above link, you can combine the two in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * execute "normal \<C-L>"
```